# Trying to edit the nose, but zooming in will display the vertices behind it

Tags: vertices

The first one in the [clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gRTr.jpg), I can get close to the nose just fine, but the second one, if I try to zoom in... then it displays like that?

How to fix that?

Maybe you can check what's going on, you can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AYQA8uioeONI-GqhYe_P6BuiK6EsmCOx).

Comment: Maybe try to change the Clip Start of your scene in the 3D view Properties panel (activated with N, on the right of your 3D view window) > View > Clip

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the *Clip Start* of your scene in the 3D View *Properties* panel (activated with <kbd>N</kbd>, on the right of your 3D View window) > *View* > *Clip* > *Start*.